# Automating Salt-Minion Installation

Tags: salt-stack

I have to setup a new salt configuration.
For minion setup I want to devise an approach. I came up with this.

1. Make entry of the new minion in `/etc/salt/roster` file so that I can use `salt-ssh`.
2. Run a salt formula to install **salt-minion** on this new minion.
3. Generate minion fingerprint with `salt-call key.finger --local` on the minion and **somehow**(still figuring) get it to master and maintain it in some file till the minion actually tries to connect.
4. When the minion actually tries to connect to the master, master makes sure about the minion identity with the stored fingerprint and then accepts the key.

Once this is done salt state can then bring the minion up to its desired state.

The manual chores associated with this:

1. I'll have to do manual entries viz. `minion-id`, `IP` and `user` in the `/etc/salt/roster` file for every new minion that I want up.

   Other than this I can't figure any drawbacks.

My questions are:

1. Is this approach feasible?
2. Are there any security risks?
3. Is a better approach already out there ?

P.S. Master and minions may or may not be on public network.

Comment: Just to make matter worse, don't forget that minions also need to verity master's identity. This finishes the trust cycle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `salt-cloud` to provision new nodes. This includes among others a provider `saltify` that will use SSH for the provisioning. [See here for the online documentation.](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2015.8/topics/cloud/saltify.html#getting-started-with-saltify) It will do the following all in one step:

- create a new set of keys for the minion
- register the minion's key with the master
- connect to the minion using SSH and bootstrap the minion with salt and the minion's keys

If you want the minions to verify the master's key once they connect, you can publish a certificate to the minions and sign the master's key with the certificate [like described here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/multimaster_pki.html). Please double-check if `saltify` already supports this.

Some time ago I have prepared a `salt-cloud` setup that works both with DigitalOcean and with Vagrant [on my Github account](https://github.com/ahus1/saltconsul-examples). The Vagrant provisioning uses `salt-cloud` with `saltify`. Have a look at the included `cheatsheet.adoc` for the Vagrant commands.

Comment: You are a life saver. I wasn't aware about this salt-cloud thing. It's so easy. Thank you.

Comment: can you have a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390216/salt-master-salt-cloud-not-acting-idempotent ?