# salt-master salt-cloud not acting idempotent

Tags: salt-stack, idempotent

I am trying to test `salt-cloud` `saltify` to deploy/install salt-minions on target machines.

I created three vagrant machines and names them **master**, **minion-01**and **minion-02**.

all the machines were same like this;

```
root@master:/home/vagrant# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

then on master I followed this http://repo.saltstack.com/#ubuntu
to install salt-master(manually ofcourse).

then in master I added these three files.

in **/etc/salt/cloud.providers:**

```
root@master:/etc/salt/cloud.providers.d# cat bare_metal.conf 
my-saltify-config:
  minion:
    master: 192.168.33.10
  driver: saltify
```

in **/etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d:**

```
root@master:/etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d# cat saltify.conf 
make_salty:
  provider: my-saltify-config
  script_args: git v2016.3.1
```

**/etc/salt/saltify-map**

```
root@master:/etc/salt# cat saltify-map 
make_salty:
  - minion-01:
      ssh_host: 192.168.33.11
      ssh_username: vagrant
      password: vagrant
  - minion-02:
      ssh_host: 192.168.33.12
      ssh_username: vagrant
      password: vagrant
```

then on minion I ran `salt-cloud -m /etc/salt/saltify-map`
It was very slow but It ran without errors.
keys of both minion-01 and minion-02 was accepted by salt master.

I could do this:

```
   root@master:/home/vagrant# salt 'minion*' test.ping
    minion-01:
        True
    minion-02:
        True
```

and this;

```
root@master:/home/vagrant# salt-key 
Accepted Keys:
minion-01
minion-02
Denied Keys:
Unaccepted Keys:
Rejected Keys:
```

**The Problem;**

Now when I again executed this `salt-cloud -m /etc/salt/saltify-map`
salt-master re-ran the whole execution and then I had this;

```
root@master:/home/vagrant# salt 'minion*' test.ping
minion-02:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
minion-01:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
```

and this;

```
root@master:/etc/salt# salt-key 
Accepted Keys:
minion-01
minion-02
Denied Keys:
minion-01
minion-02
Unaccepted Keys:
Rejected Keys:
```

In short salt-cloud is not acting **idempotent**.

What am I doing wrong ?

The second problem is, though on the first run `salt-cloud -m /etc/salt/saltify-map` installs and accepts key of **minion-01** and **minion-02** on salt-master, but the minion machines have all these things installed along with `salt-minion`

```
root@minion-02:/home/vagrant# salt
salt         salt-call    salt-cp      salt-master  salt-proxy   salt-ssh     salt-unity
salt-api     salt-cloud   salt-key     salt-minion  salt-run     salt-syndic
```

How do I make sure that only `salt-minion` gets installed.

Thanks.

PS:

```
root@master:/etc/salt# salt-master --version
salt-master 2016.3.1 (Boron)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You write: "It was very slow"**:

You have set `script_args` to values that install everything from Github from source. You might want to remove the parameters (or use different parameters) to have a fast installation of a pre-packaged version. Please see https://github.com/saltstack/salt-bootstrap and specifically `bootstrap-salt.sh` for the available options.

**You write: "salt-cloud is not acting idempotent"**:

You're doing everything correctly. `salt-cloud` is not idempotent. As far as I know it is not designed to be idempotent.

**You write: "the minion machines have all these things installed along with salt-minion"**

It might be the case due to using the `git` parameters and installing it from source. Please try a pre-packaged version of Salt.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant doesn't destroy the machines between runs, does it?

By the looks of it, on the second run the salt minions have started with new keys and re-registered with the master. Because they've got the same names it's all got confused .....

Try "vagrant destroy" before running, so that the machines are fresh each time?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is also being tracked as a bug in Salt though at present, it cannot be duplicated: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/34687

Answer (score 0):

It appears its a `saltify` bug. So, can't do anything about this question. The bug is reported and hopefully this will get solved in a future release.